# I have multiple primary keys, how do I go about the format?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

I have an assignment where I need to create a database model for a company. However, there are so many primary keys in so many tables. According to my teacher a good primary key only consists of numbers. However, I have about 20 primary keys. Does this mean I make my first primary key
Employee key: 9999999

Customer key: 99999999 (7 characters)

Product key : 999999999 (8 characters)

Tour key    : 9999999999 (9 characters)

Comment: 1) PK can definitely have more than numbers. 2) why wouldnt you start at 1?

Comment: 3) What do you mean by your "first primary key"? Each table has its own primary key. Please show us the model you've come up with.

Comment: @dfundako That's the format (like in the data dictionary). so the range for customer key is 1000000-9999999. This way its not messy. It won't go  ...9, 10, 11, 12... 98, 99, 100, 101...,999, 1000

Comment: @duskwuff I mean like, the primary key in customers should be 7 number's long and product should be 8 numbers long (so the primary keys are distinguishable)

Comment: @PaulShan You don't need to distinguish PK's like that. You can have 10,000 tables and all can start with a PK of 1 called ID.

Comment: @dfundako How would you distinguish primary keys?

Comment: @PaulShan What makes you think they need to be distinguishable?

Comment: @duskwuff What if the a customer goes "what ID do I have right here? Is it my tour ID or my customer ID"

Comment: You don't know without context. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

As our friend @duskwuff said in the comments, you don't have to distinguish. The function of a PK, is to have a single value from the table it belongs, and not a single value from the hole database.
For example:

Employee key belongs to Employee table

Customer key belongs to Customer table

and etc.

when you fetch a value from the key, you have to know the table in which you want to fetch, so you will test the value with the specified table key. I made myself understood?